# How do you know if the right agent is being used?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops, let's say you have three self-hosted agents that run on three different Windows Servers and they are all part of the Default agent pool. When you create a build you're only able to specify what agent pool to pull from. If your wanting to create the build to run a specific agent (windows server) where do you specify this or how does it know to grab the right agent?? If you could please provide and explanation on how this works.

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the agents be in different pools if you want to specify which one to use?

Comment: hi jssteele89, have the answers of rimaz and mine helped with your issue? –

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add different **capabilities** for each of those Agents (even if they are in the same pool). Add them as User defined capabilities.

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#configure-agent-capabilities
[image]

And then in your azure pipelines yaml, you can add that user defined capability as a **demand** under the pool used : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines#pool-name-demands-vmimage

[image]

Azure will then only use an agent in that pool that matches all your demands.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we suppose that the definition for [agent pool demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands) of yaml schema could work for your scenario

If you are using classic pipeline editor, you could also define your self-hosted agent pools demands to specify the specific capabilities for the agents.

[image]